# C# - How to call a method from static void main

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have some code in static void main, although I would like it to call the startremdup method (as it calls the RemoveDuplicate, with the appropriate parameters) from static void main, I have tried startremdup();

```
private void RemoveDuplicate(string sourceFilePath, string destinationFilePath)
{
    var readLines = File.ReadAllLines(sourceFilePath, Encoding.Default);

    File.WriteAllLines(destinationFilePath, readLines.Distinct().ToArray(), Encoding.Default);
}


private void startremdup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RemoveDuplicate("C:\test.txt", "C:\test2.txt");
}
```

Comment: Are these methods in the same class as your main method?

Comment: You can't call an instance method from a static method without first creating an instance of the class in which it belongs. Try creating an instance of the class, i.e. `SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();`, where `startremdup` and `RemoveDuplicate` are part of `SomeClass`, then access the methods via `SomeClass`, i.e. `sc.startremdup();`. Alternately, if they're part of the static class, you need to label the methods static as well.

Comment: Also, what are you passing in the object and EventArgs params to your startremdup method?....also....startremdup is a terrible method name...it would be clearer if you simply called the RemoveDuplicate() method rather than wrapping it in an obscurely named method.

Comment: @Jamie: I assume the startremdump is called on an event (like a button click), hence the sender and eventargs parameters, which are required for basic event handlers in C#.

Comment: @Mannimarco He says he's calling it from his main method. *shrug*

Comment: @Jamie: I'm gonna hope that he's only calling it from main for testing purposes. Otherwise this may be a lost cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make both `startremdup()` and `RemoveDuplicate()` static.

```
private static void RemoveDuplicate(string sourceFilePath, string destinationFilePath)
{
    var readLines = File.ReadAllLines(sourceFilePath, Encoding.Default);

    File.WriteAllLines(destinationFilePath, readLines.Distinct().ToArray(), Encoding.Default);
}


private static void startremdup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RemoveDuplicate("C:\test.txt", "C:\test2.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 13):

`startremdup` is an *instance* method. That means you need to call it on an instance of whatever class it's contained in. For example:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.startremdup(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Personally it looks like it should be a static method to start with - and preferably one with a more sensible name - but that's why it's not working at the time.

If I were you, I'd actually put down your current task and pick up a good introductory C# book - learn the difference between static and instance members, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Make your methods `static` as well.

Answer (score 2):

startremdup and removeduplicate need to be declared as static if you are calling it from a static method (such as Main())

Answer (score 1):

You can't call nonstatic methods from a static method unless you call them on an object reference. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either make both of those methods static, or create an instance of your `Main` class and call the method from that.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `private static void startremdup(object sender, EventArgs e)` since static method can't call instance methods because they don't have `this`.