# I made a method and if I call it errors c#. How do I fix it?

Tags: c#

This is the code I am using

```
using System;

namespace cs_Program_5_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrintNumber();

            //Wait
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private void PrintNumber()
        {
            Random numGen = new Random();
            int number = numGen.Next(0, 10);
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you call a method from static main()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728494/how-do-you-call-a-method-from-static-main) Change PrintNumber to `static`.

Comment: Does this answer yourt question? [C# - How to call a method from static void main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388194/c-sharp-how-to-call-a-method-from-static-void-main) and [Call function from Main()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997465/call-function-from-main)

Answer (score -1):

The reason that there's an error message is because you're trying to call a non-static method inside a static method (which C# doesn't support).

Change your `PrintNumber` signature to this:

```
private static void PrintNumber()
```

Answer (score -1):

Make `PrintNumber()` static.

```
static void PrintNumber()
```